# Will a cyclist be able to pedal during free fall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-fall

Assume that he is seated on the cycle and his waist is tied to the seat.

Comment: Yes - but if he accelerates the wheels, the entire bike will start to spin backwards (conservation of angular momentum)

Comment: Yes! you don't even need to experiment. What do you think the astronauts in the ISS do for exercise? Only thing would be that the cyclist should not accelerate. then the orientation of the cycle will change which will be not good for the cyclist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the tether between waist and seat will be in tension, allowing the cyclist to exert pressure against the pedals without separating the cyclist from bicycle.

The cyclist may need to grasp the handlebars also to prevent the bicycle rotating out of reach of the cyclists feet.

In the case of a unicycle, I think the cyclist will experience some difficulty in maintaining the orientation of the cycle in a position suited to pedalling. It may be necessary to increase the amount of tieing of waist to seat.

In the case of a unicycle operated by an adult human monopod wearing mittens in free-fall, I fear the results will not be good for lateral alignment of cycle to cyclist, but I look forward to reading your research paper and viewing the accompanying videos.

See Floris' comments for some insight into the results of the cyclist being able to perform this action.

Suggested apparatus:

[image]
<sup>Image © unknown, probably by [DM Schwartz](http://www.bikeradar.com/road/news/article/is-this-bike-without-a-seat-the-end-of-saddle-sore-41469/?CPN=RSS&SOURCE=BRGENHOME)</sup>

Comment: I have a feeling that if try to pedal cycle will start rotating. What can stop it from that phenomena.